# Visual Studio webbrowser display errors

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I created a new C# project in Visual Studio Community 2015 and added a WebBrowser.

The only code I wrote was

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/");
}
```

But it trows some javascript errors and in some sites the images don't load, script is not executed, it appears the CSS is not loaded.

This one is in Internet Explorer 11 (i'm indeed using windows 10)

[image: IE]

and this one in Visual Studio (says windows 8), and the style is not the same, it should be identical.

[image: Visual studio]

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40922493/101087

Comment: Setting the version in the registry to IE11 solved the problem, but it still displays Windows8. I'll just assume it's not important...