# Google API to export/import Calendar Events in my application

Tags: api, calendar

A use `Google API` to export/import `Calendar` Events in my application(using `MS webbrowser` control almost two years.
In a last month there is a problem:

Here is the `auth`. request:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=595121125761-jtgfohb86gvpl75au1l6f3h9cdjvoi7e.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.imaster.co.il/interactive/code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&login_hint=info@imaster.co.il&include_granted_scopes=true&approval_prompt=force

SO
When it runs on `MS webbrowser` control, the `ALLOW` button unlikely disabled
(Webbrowser Control.bmp)

BUT
When it runs on `Internet Explorer` (on the same computer), the `ALLOW` button propertly enabled
(IExplorer.bmp)

It happens on different computers.
I need your help to solve it.
There are two screen attached.

2 Attachments
[image: img]

Comment: It is probably a security feature of the Google oAuth2 system. Does your web browser control interpret JavaScript? If you are using C# try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922370/allow-system-windows-forms-webbrowser-to-run-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents/38514446#38514446

Comment: The MS webcontrol is standart. Used by VB 6 Classic despot application. Till December 2019 it was ok, but suddenly it stoped work. Now all my oAuth2 clients are unable to export their calendar event into google calendar.