# Run java applets on a wpf web browser

Tags: java, c#, wpf, applet, webbrowser-control

I am building a WPF (VS2015 C# .NET 4.5) application that is using WebBrowser control. I am trying to using this to remotely monitor a pump system which has embedded web server. That web server contain a java applet which working as a HMI (Human Machine Interface). Problem is java applets are not running in my WebBrowser control. I tested the java with [java test page](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp). But it does not detect java. When I am trying with IE 11 it detects the java and no problem for applets. I did tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142594/allowing-javascript-to-run-on-a-windows-form-web-browser). But nothing works for me.

Is there any way to solve this? Or is there any WPF controllers for running java applets?

Thank you very much...!

Comment: 1) Applets have become completely unworkable for sites dealing to 'all comers' on the internet.  Safari and FF both block applets by default, and Chrome and IE are set to completely remove support for them.  It is best to transition away from applets to pure JS/HTML sooner rather than later. 2) To expand on that: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Thanks andrew for your comment. I know that chrome is not support java from version 42. But IE 11 still supports. Is there .net Java Applet Viewer or something?

Comment: *"Is there .net Java Applet Viewer or something?"* DYM inside or outside a browser? If 'outside' there are easier ways to view an applet other than displaying the applet in an application (I've written Java based desktop applications that can display applets).

Comment: No I mean inside the WPF application.

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be slightly trickier than loading an applet in a Java based application though, in that: 1) An applet is a native Java component  that can then be added to a Java application just like any other Java component. 2) A JVM is already available. - In fact *"..using this to remotely monitor a pump system which has embedded web server.."* I'd guess (without any certainty) it would be easier to develop that in pure WPF than to integrate a Java applet that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

After long hard time I found the solution. If you want to enable java content in your WebBrowser control you should specify the IE version as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142594/allowing-javascript-to-run-on-a-windows-form-web-browser). But you have to careful with your JRE and your application. Both of them should be 32bit or 64bit. Otherwise java applets won't run.